# Logical statement, is the deduction correct?

Tags: logic, truth

I found a theorem that is like this:

If A and B are true, then C is true if and only if D is true.
In other words:

Can we deduce,

If D and ( not (A) or not (B) ) then not (C)?

Of course "and", "or", and "not" are logical operators.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. You get counterexamples when C and D are both true and either A or B is false. I'm assuming this is an elementary logic question and your 'if' is a material conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If A and B are not both true then no statement is made about C whatsoever.

Answer (score -3):

> I found a theorem that is like this:
>
> If A and B are true, then C is true if and only if D is true. In other words:
>
> Can we deduce,
>
> If D and ( not (A) or not (B) ) then not (C)?
>
> Of course "and", "or", and "not" are logical operators.

Your "*theorem*":

> *If A and B are true, then C is true if and only if D is true*

translate formally as follows:

> A ∧ B ⊢ C ⇔ D

This just means that A and B together imply that C is equivalent to D.

This is of course self-evidently false, therefore not a theorem.

I think you know that already.

However, if the "*theorem*" you found is:

> (A ∧ B) → ((C ⇔ D)) ⊢ (D ∧ (¬A ∨ ¬B)) → ¬C

Then it is not a theorem!

There are cases where (A ∧ B) → ((C ⇔ D)) is true and (D ∧ (¬A ∨ ¬B)) → ¬C is false.

So, it is not true that if (A ∧ B) → ((C ⇔ D)) is true, then (D ∧ (¬A ∨ ¬B)) → ¬C is true.

In fact, if (A ∧ B) → ((C ⇔ D)) is true, then (D ∧ (¬A ∨ ¬B)) → ¬C is false.

This means that we do have a theorem, namely:

> (A ∧ B) → ((C ⇔ D)) ⊢ ¬((D ∧ (¬A ∨ ¬B)) → ¬C)

And now it is really a theorem.

Happy New Year to all!

Comment: Clearly that’s not what OP meant. They’re asking if A&B⊢C<->D is enough to conclude D&(~Av~B)⊢~C.

Comment: @PW_246 Yes, I understand that, but this is not what it says.

Comment: Why is "A and B together imply that C is equivalent to D" "of course self-evidently false"?

Comment: @Stef Why do you ask?

Comment: @Speakpigeon In order to get an answer? I have no idea why you think it's false, nor why it's "obviously self-evidently" false.

Comment: @Stef Really?! Come on! I can't believe you.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Okay then. Maybe we're not speaking the same language. This interaction between you and me reminds me of a conversation I've had with two people, who were talking about someone called "Yellowstar". I asked them who Yellowstar was, and they replied that they couldn't believe that I really didn't know.

Comment: In their community, it was inconceivable that someone might not know who this Yellowstar person was. Perhaps in your mind it's inconceivable that I might not know why you think that something is false. I still don't know who Yellowstar is, and I still don't know why you think this theorem is false.

Comment: @Stef "*Perhaps in your mind it's inconceivable that I might not know why you think that something is false.*" Nothing to do with why I think the implication is false. What I cannot conceive is that you should not understand by yourself that the implication is false. If you don't understand this one, how could you understand that any false implication is false? Could you give an example of a reasonably simple false implication and explain why it is false according to you?

Comment: @Speakpigeon My best guess is that you are interpreting the words of the OP in a different way, which leads you to conclude that this theorem is false. Since I cannot read your mind, I have no idea how you are interpreting things.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Note that the OP never said what A, B, C and D were. It seems completely impossible for me to conclude that the theorem is false without knowing what A, B, C and D are. Surely you can come up with a trivial example of definitions of A,B,C,D for which the theorem is ***not*** false?

Comment: @Stef "*Surely you can come up with a trivial example of definitions of A,B,C,D for which the theorem is not false?*" The purported theorem is just A ∧ B ⊢ C ⇔ D. It does not specify any value for A, B, C and D. If we specified A, B, C or D, it would no longer be the same theorem.

Comment: *“In fact, if (A ∧ B) → ((C ⇔ D)) is true, then (D ∧ (¬A ∨ ¬B)) → ¬C is false.“* Huh? Both the original formula and the formula I quoted are satisfiable when A, B, C, and D are all true of all false; in most logics, it follows that both are in fact true.

Comment: @PW_246 "*in most logics*" We are clearly not talking about the same thing. By "*logics*", in the plural, you presumably mean various formal systems, systems which are purely theoretic. By "logic", in the singular, I mean the real thing, real thing according to which the implication (A ∧ B) → ((C ⇔ D)) ⊢ ¬((D ∧ (¬A ∨ ¬B)) → ¬C) is true.

Comment: @Speakpigeon you mean an inconsistent logic? I don’t think the above even holds in Connexive Logic, but I could be wrong. Either way, Connexive Logic is inconsistent.

Comment: @PW_246 "*you mean an inconsistent logic?*" Ok, I give up.